# Microblaze linux stop booting at "bootconsole[earlyser0] disabled"

Tags: linux, embedded, dts, buildroot, device-tree

I want embed linux on a nexys 4 ddr board.
I made an essential system: microblaze+ddr+uartlite+gpios
Linux image is made by build root 2014.05

Linux boot stop after bootconsole[earlyser0] disabled.

some thing of strange happen: i put "console=ttyUL0" and BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="ttyUL0" but, booting i see 40600000.serial.ttyUL1, there is some explication?

any way also putting UL1 in in dts and defconfig i get same result.

my dts.

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    compatible = "xlnx,microblaze";
    model = "Xilinx MicroBlaze";
    memory {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x80000000 0x8000000>;
        };
    aliases {
        serial0 = &axi_uartlite_0;
        };
    chosen {
        bootargs = "console=ttyUL1";
        linux,stdout-path = "/amba_pl/serial@40600000";
        };
    cpus {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #cpus = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        microblaze_0: cpu@0 {
            bus-handle = <&amba_pl>;
            clock-frequency = <100000000>;
            clocks = <&clk_cpu>;
            compatible = "xlnx,microblaze-9.4";
            d-cache-baseaddr = <0x80000000>;
            d-cache-highaddr = <0x87ffffff>;
            d-cache-line-size = <0x10>;
            d-cache-size = <0x4000>;
            device_type = "cpu";
            i-cache-baseaddr = <0x80000000>;
            i-cache-highaddr = <0x87ffffff>;
            i-cache-line-size = <0x20>;
            i-cache-size = <0x4000>;
            interrupt-handle = <&microblaze_0_axi_intc>;
            model = "microblaze,9.4";
            timebase-frequency = <100000000>;
            xlnx,addr-tag-bits = <0xd>;
            xlnx,allow-dcache-wr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,allow-icache-wr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,area-optimized = <0x0>;
            xlnx,async-interrupt = <0x1>;
            xlnx,avoid-primitives = <0x0>;
            xlnx,base-vectors = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,branch-target-cache-size = <0x0>;
            xlnx,cache-byte-size = <0x4000>;
            xlnx,d-axi = <0x1>;
            xlnx,d-lmb = <0x1>;
            xlnx,data-size = <0x20>;
            xlnx,dcache-addr-tag = <0xd>;
            xlnx,dcache-always-used = <0x1>;
            xlnx,dcache-byte-size = <0x4000>;
            xlnx,dcache-data-width = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-force-tag-lutram = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-line-len = <0x4>;
            xlnx,dcache-use-writeback = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dcache-victims = <0x8>;
            xlnx,debug-counter-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,debug-enabled = <0x1>;
            xlnx,debug-event-counters = <0x5>;
            xlnx,debug-external-trace = <0x0>;
            xlnx,debug-latency-counters = <0x1>;
            xlnx,debug-profile-size = <0x0>;
            xlnx,debug-trace-size = <0x2000>;
            xlnx,div-zero-exception = <0x1>;
            xlnx,dynamic-bus-sizing = <0x0>;
            xlnx,ecc-use-ce-exception = <0x0>;
            xlnx,edge-is-positive = <0x1>;
            xlnx,enable-discrete-ports = <0x0>;
            xlnx,endianness = <0x1>;
            xlnx,fault-tolerant = <0x0>;
            xlnx,fpu-exception = <0x0>;
            xlnx,freq = <0x5f5e100>;
            xlnx,fsl-exception = <0x0>;
            xlnx,fsl-links = <0x0>;
            xlnx,i-axi = <0x0>;
            xlnx,i-lmb = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-always-used = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-data-width = <0x0>;
            xlnx,icache-force-tag-lutram = <0x0>;
            xlnx,icache-line-len = <0x8>;
            xlnx,icache-streams = <0x1>;
            xlnx,icache-victims = <0x8>;
            xlnx,ill-opcode-exception = <0x1>;
            xlnx,interconnect = <0x2>;
            xlnx,interrupt-is-edge = <0x0>;
            xlnx,lockstep-select = <0x0>;
            xlnx,lockstep-slave = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mmu-dtlb-size = <0x4>;
            xlnx,mmu-itlb-size = <0x2>;
            xlnx,mmu-privileged-instr = <0x0>;
            xlnx,mmu-tlb-access = <0x3>;
            xlnx,mmu-zones = <0x2>;
            xlnx,num-sync-ff-clk = <0x2>;
            xlnx,num-sync-ff-clk-debug = <0x2>;
            xlnx,num-sync-ff-clk-irq = <0x1>;
            xlnx,num-sync-ff-dbg-clk = <0x1>;
            xlnx,number-of-pc-brk = <0x1>;
            xlnx,number-of-rd-addr-brk = <0x0>;
            xlnx,number-of-wr-addr-brk = <0x0>;
            xlnx,opcode-0x0-illegal = <0x1>;
            xlnx,optimization = <0x0>;
            xlnx,pc-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,pvr = <0x2>;
            xlnx,pvr-user1 = <0x00>;
            xlnx,pvr-user2 = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,reset-msr = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,sco = <0x0>;
            xlnx,trace = <0x0>;
            xlnx,unaligned-exceptions = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-barrel = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-branch-target-cache = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-config-reset = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-dcache = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-div = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-ext-brk = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-ext-nm-brk = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-extended-fsl-instr = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-fpu = <0x0>;
            xlnx,use-hw-mul = <0x2>;
            xlnx,use-icache = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-interrupt = <0x2>;
            xlnx,use-mmu = <0x3>;
            xlnx,use-msr-instr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-pcmp-instr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-reorder-instr = <0x1>;
            xlnx,use-stack-protection = <0x0>;
        };
    };
    clocks {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        clk_cpu: clk_cpu@0 {
            #clock-cells = <0>;
            clock-frequency = <100000000>;
            clock-output-names = "clk_cpu";
            compatible = "fixed-clock";
            reg = <0>;
        };
        clk_bus_0: clk_bus_0@1 {
            #clock-cells = <0>;
            clock-frequency = <100000000>;
            clock-output-names = "clk_bus_0";
            compatible = "fixed-clock";
            reg = <1>;
        };
    };
    amba_pl: amba_pl {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        ranges ;
        axi_gpio_0: gpio@40000000 {
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-gpio-1.00.a";
            gpio-controller ;
            reg = <0x40000000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,all-inputs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-inputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-outputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,dout-default-2 = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,gpio-width = <0x10>;
            xlnx,gpio2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,interrupt-present = <0x0>;
            xlnx,is-dual = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tri-default = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
            xlnx,tri-default-2 = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
        };
        axi_gpio_1: gpio@40010000 {
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-gpio-1.00.a";
            gpio-controller ;
            reg = <0x40010000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,all-inputs = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-inputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,dout-default-2 = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,gpio-width = <0x10>;
            xlnx,gpio2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,interrupt-present = <0x0>;
            xlnx,is-dual = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tri-default = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
            xlnx,tri-default-2 = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
        };
        axi_timer_0: timer@41c00000 {
            clock-frequency = <100000000>;
            clocks = <&clk_bus_0>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-timer-1.00.a";
            interrupt-parent = <&microblaze_0_axi_intc>;
            interrupts = <0 2>;
            reg = <0x41c00000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,count-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,gen0-assert = <0x1>;
            xlnx,gen1-assert = <0x1>;
            xlnx,one-timer-only = <0x0>;
            xlnx,trig0-assert = <0x1>;
            xlnx,trig1-assert = <0x1>;
        };
        axi_uartlite_0: serial@40600000 {
            clock-frequency = <100000000>;
            clocks = <&clk_bus_0>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-uartlite-1.00.a";
            current-speed = <115200>;
            device_type = "serial";
            interrupt-parent = <&microblaze_0_axi_intc>;
            interrupts = <1 0>;
            port-number = <1>;
            reg = <0x40600000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,baudrate = <0x1c200>;
            xlnx,data-bits = <0x8>;
            xlnx,odd-parity = <0x0>;
            xlnx,s-axi-aclk-freq-hz-d = <0x64>;
            xlnx,use-parity = <0x0>;
        };
        microblaze_0_axi_intc: interrupt-controller@41200000 {
            #interrupt-cells = <2>;
            compatible = "xlnx,xps-intc-1.00.a";
            interrupt-controller ;
            reg = <0x41200000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,kind-of-intr = <0x2>;
            xlnx,num-intr-inputs = <0x2>;
        };
        mig_7series_0: memory-controller@80000000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,mig-7series-2.3";
            device_type = "memory";
            reg = <0x80000000 0x8000000>;
        };
    };
};
```

my defconfig

```
CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE="rootfs.cpio"
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_GZIP=y
# CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE is not set
CONFIG_EXPERT=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_EXTRA_PASS=y
# CONFIG_HOTPLUG is not set
# CONFIG_BASE_FULL is not set
# CONFIG_FUTEX is not set
# CONFIG_EPOLL is not set
# CONFIG_SIGNALFD is not set
# CONFIG_SHMEM is not set
CONFIG_SLAB=y
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG is not set
# CONFIG_OPT_LIB_ASM is not set
CONFIG_KERNEL_BASE_ADDR=0x80000000
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_FAMILY="artix7"
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_BARREL=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_CONFIG_RESET=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_BRANCH_TARTGET_CACHE=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_DCACHE=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_EXT_BRK=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_DIV=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_EXT_NM_BRK=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_EXTENDED_FSL_INSTR=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_FPU=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_HW_MUL=2
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_ICACHE=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_INTERRUPT=2
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_MMU=3
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_MSR_INSTR=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_PCMP_INSTR=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_REORDER_INSTR=1
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_USE_STACK_PROTECTION=0
CONFIG_XILINX_MICROBLAZE0_HW_VER="9.4"
CONFIG_HZ_100=y
CONFIG_MMU=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=y
CONFIG_NET=y
CONFIG_PACKET=y
CONFIG_UNIX=y
CONFIG_INET=y
# CONFIG_INET_LRO is not set
# CONFIG_IPV6 is not set
CONFIG_PROC_DEVICETREE=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=8192
# CONFIG_NETDEVICES=y
# CONFIG_NET_ETHERNET=y
# CONFIG_XILINX_EMACLITE=y
# CONFIG_INPUT is not set
# CONFIG_SERIO is not set
# CONFIG_VT is not set
CONFIG_SERIAL_UARTLITE=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_UARTLITE_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_HW_RANDOM is not set
# CONFIG_HWMON is not set
# CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_EXT2_FS=y
# CONFIG_DNOTIFY is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_CIFS=y
CONFIG_CIFS_STATS=y
CONFIG_CIFS_STATS2=y
CONFIG_PARTITION_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_DETECT_HUNG_TASK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_SLAB=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK=y
# CONFIG_CRYPTO_ANSI_CPRNG is not set
```

and config

```
BR2_microblaze=y
BR2_microblazeel=y

BR2_ARCH="microblazeel"
BR2_ENDIAN="LITTLE"


BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="ttyUL1"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE_115200=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE="115200"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_TERM="vt100"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_OPTIONS=""
# BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_TAR is not set
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_INITRAMFS=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="board/digilent/n4ddr/n4ddr_defconfig"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_DTS=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH="board/digilent/n4ddr/n4ddr.dts"

BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_HOSTNAME="n4ddr"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ISSUE="Welcome to Digilent + n4ddr + Microblaze + Linux + gmv"
```

i enclose also the uart output

[image]

some help please

Comment: Try editing the command line (that's passed to the Kernel from the boot program) to `console=ttyUL1,115200n8`, since that's the only serial port that you have configured, and the mode is completely specified.

Comment: sawdust - thank you for answer, I change the line to console=ttyUL1,115200n8, but nothing change